# Cancel order option in all status

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status

In Magento how to cancel order after invoice and shipment. i am using Magento 1.9

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I want to cancel order after invoice and shipment also

Answer (score 2):

If there is an invoice, it's too late not "cancel", you need to refund the invoice, i.e. create a credit memo.